# Can't install Flash Player on any of my browsers "wrong architecture i386" using Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flash

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed an Ubuntu version 11.04, 32 bit on 64 bit CPU. I downloaded Google Chrome, Chromium and Firefox and I can't install Flash Player on any of them.

I went to YouTube and when asked to install Flash Player I followed the link.

For Google Chrome:
- I tried choosing ".deb for Ubuntu" and I get "wrong architecture 'i386'"
- I tried "apt for Ubuntu 9.04+" - the Ubuntu Software Center loads. I install but no success in playing Flash later.

On Firefox I also downloaded the .deb file and got the "wrong architecture" error. 
I also downloaded flash square plugin 64 - but I got a tar.gz with libflashplayer.so that doesnt automatically open in any software.
suggestions?

Comment: `uname -a` says what?

Comment: Thanks.it says : 
Linux ubuntu 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This means you have the 64-bit version of Ubuntu (AMD64 aka x86_64). Historically there have been a few problems with Flash on 64-bit Linux (i.e. Flash has worked better on 32-bit).

Answer (score 5):

You did *not* install 32-bit Ubuntu. Get the 64-bit Flash Player, if there is one. Or install a 32-bit browser.

Comment: Install [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?platform=linux). Get the 64-bit .deb. The advantage here is that Flash is bundled *and* Google tend to be quicker at fixing bugs in Flash Player than Adobe! It won't solve your Firefox Flash issues mind you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install a working Flash plugin automatically with apt-get (or aptitude if you prefer - I do).

A simple:

```
sudo aptitude install flash-installer
```

should do. If that doesn't work for you, you may try using this repository:
https://launchpad.net/~sevenmachines/+archive/flash

You will find the instructions on the linked website. I haven't tried it myself because the default Flash version works fine for me (Kubuntu 11.04 64 bit on a Core i5 Sony laptop), but I've read on various forums that this sometimes solved issues for other users.